# TypeError: get() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given) error in Python

Tags: python, django

I have checked few of the answers in SO, but nothing worked for me. I'm still giving the same error:

> TypeError: get() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Can anybody check the following code and let me know what I have done wrong?

my '**views.py**' is as follows

```
def get(self, request, tag):
        print("Tag for tagging :")
        data_loader = SvnDataLoader()
        print("Two :")
        ss = SubsystemRevision.get_subsystem_for_tag(tag)
        print("Subsystem is %s", ss)
        try:
            print("inside try")
            pr = subprocess.Popen(['perl', './svntasktag.pl', 'ss'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            data = pr.communicate()
            context = {'data':data}
        except TagHistoryMissing:
            data = 'Tag is missing.'
        except SvnException as e:
            data = "Problem while trying to fetch tag-history from svn. Try again later"
            #logger.error("SvnException %s while trying to fetch the tag %s" % (str(e), tag.name))

        return render_to_response('pai_app/create_tag.html', {'data': data}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: remove `tag` from the parameters. Or modify the `dispatch` method to pass the tag to the get method.

Comment: Either remove `tag` from the function or define it as `tag=some_default_value` .For ex: `tag='mytag'`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know that **self** refers to the object itself. You can add another argument and you error will be solved e.g.

```
def get(self, request, tag, foobar):
   ...
```

But it's better to know what arguments you want to have and what you are passing to the function.

The second point is that you are using get() in your views. Usually it is not the good practice to use method names for the functions (we have Model.objects.get()). So it is better to change your function to something like **get_tag()** to prevent any type of conflicts during development. Don't forget to update your app modules! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of your response.I am using this get method in a separate class called "class create_tag which present in "classviews". So I used get() function directly. I am trying your suggestion and hope it will work. Thank you all once again

Answer (score 0):

If your function not in a class,you can use

```
def get(request, tag):
    pass
```

Because the params **self** not be used in your function.

In django function views,the first params must be a request obj instance.